# JAVA FX - could not able update the Cells value during the save Action

Tags: java

I have written a java FX application which reads the xml file and displays the contents where
I am trying to edit the contents of the cell and save where the changes I will be writing into a xml file but its not giving the updated values from the form.

Code:

```
package application;
    
public class Main extends Application {
    
    FTPLogic ftplogic = new FTPLogic();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Text scenetitle = new Text("LOG IN");
        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Label host = new Label("HOST");
        host.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
        grid.add(host, 0, 1);

        TextField hostTextField = new TextField();
        
        grid.add(hostTextField, 1, 1);

        Label port = new Label("PORT");
        port.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
        grid.add(port, 0, 2);
        
        TextField portTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(portTextField, 1, 2);
        portTextField.setText("22");
        
        Label uname = new Label("USERNAME");
        uname.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
        grid.add(uname, 0, 3);
        
        TextField unameTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(unameTextField, 1, 3);
        
        Label pwd = new Label("PASSWORD");
        pwd.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
        grid.add(pwd, 0, 4);
        
        

        PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwBox, 1, 4);
        Button btn = new Button("Connect");
        btn.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 5);
        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);
        
        //scene.getStylesheets().add(ConfigDataManager.class.getResource("activity.css").toExternalForm());
        BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("file:background_image.jpg",2000,1400,false,true),
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                  BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
        //then you set to your node
        grid.setBackground(new Background(myBI));
        
        
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
                Document configDataXml;
                
                try {
                
                /*hostname = hostTextField.getText();
                portval = portTextField.getText();
                username = unameTextField.getText();
                password = pwBox.getText();
                System.out.println("Host is:"+hostname+" Port is:"+portval+" Username is:"+username+"Password is:"+password);
                configDataXml = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("ConfigData.xml");
*/              configDataXml = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("ConfigData.xml");
                configDataXml = ftplogic.readFile();
                NodeList tabs = XmlUtils.getNodeList(configDataXml, "/operation/setConfigdata/@name");
                for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getLength(); i++) {
                    String tabname = tabs.item(i).getTextContent();
                    ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String xpath = "/operation/setConfigdata[@name='" + tabname + "']/values/@value";
                    NodeList values = XmlUtils.getNodeList(configDataXml, xpath);
                    for (int j = 0; j < values.getLength(); j++) {
                        valueList.add(values.item(j).getTextContent());
                    }
                    ListView listView = new ListView();
                    listView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
                    listView.editCommitEvent();
                    listView.setEditable(true);
                    listView.layout();
                    
                    for (int k = 0; k < values.getLength(); k++) {
                        
                        listView.getItems().add(values.item(k).getTextContent());
                    }
                    
                    Tab tab = new Tab(tabname, listView);
                    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
                }

                VBox vBox = new VBox(50);
                Button save = new Button("  Save  ");
                //save.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                save.setMinSize(20, 20);
                save.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
               
                Button logout = new Button("Log Out");
                logout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                logout.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
                //vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                Button addvalue = new Button("Add Value");
                //addvalue.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                addvalue.setMinSize(10, 10);
                addvalue.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD,15));
                HBox hBox = new HBox(40);
                hBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
                hBox.getChildren().addAll(logout);
                HBox hBox2 = new HBox(40);
                hBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                hBox2.getChildren().addAll(addvalue,save);
                System.out.println("Added Value");
                hBox.setMaxHeight(100);
                 BackgroundImage myBI1= new BackgroundImage(new Image("file:background_image.jpg",2000,1400,false,true),
                            BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                              BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
                    //then you set to your node
                 vBox.setBackground(new Background(myBI1));
                vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox,tabPane,hBox2);
                

                save.setOnAction(value -> {
                    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
                    ObservableList<Tab> tabsList = tabPane.getTabs();
                    for (Tab tab : tabsList) {
                        Node node = tab.getContent();
                        ListView listView = (ListView) node.lookup("ListView");
                        System.out.println("listView.getItems() Valus is:"+listView.getItems());
                        if(listView.getItems()!=null && !"".equals(listView.getItems().toString())) {
                            map.put(tab.getText(), listView.getItems());
                        }
                    }

                    createXML(map);
                });
                logout.setOnAction(value -> {
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
                });
                
                addvalue.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                    ListView listView = (ListView)tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getContent().lookup("ListView");
                    listView.getItems().add(listView.getItems().size(),"Add Value");
                    //listView.edit(index);
                });
                
                
                Scene scene1 = new Scene(vBox,1280,1400);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
                primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
                primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                //primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            }catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }}

            
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Configuration Updater");
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:icon.png"));
        
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public void createXML(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
            Element root = doc.createElement("operation");
            doc.appendChild(root);
            if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    List<String> lst = entry.getValue();

                    Element root1 = doc.createElement("setConfigdata");
                    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("name");
                    attr.setValue(entry.getKey());
                    root1.setAttributeNode(attr);
                    root.appendChild(root1);

                    if (lst != null && !lst.isEmpty()) {
                        for (String s : lst) {
                            if(!s.isEmpty()) {
                            Element values = doc.createElement("values");
                            Attr attr1 = doc.createAttribute("value");
                            attr1.setValue(s);
                            values.setAttributeNode(attr1);
                            values.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(" "));
                            root1.appendChild(values);
                      }
                      }
                    }

                }
            }
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            trans.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", Integer.toString(2));
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw); 
            trans.transform(source, result);
            String xmlString = sw.toString();
            ftplogic.writeFileLocal(formatXML(xmlString));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
     private static String formatXML(String xml) throws TransformerException {

         // write data to xml file
         TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

         // pretty print by indention
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

         // add standalone="yes", add line break before the root element
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");

         StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
         StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
         transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(output));

         return output.toString();

     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My GUI:

[image: Screenshot of GUI]

Comment: First of all, I would declare `ListView` as `ListView<String>`

Comment: yes i have changed it string now but during the save those changes are not selected